# Error Detected - Paypal

Tags: forms, paypal, sandbox

I can't understand why I get this annoying error message when I test out the paypal button in sandbox test site.

Error Detected

> PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem.

I've tried using different test accounts and I get the same thing.

Here are the codes for the paypal button:

```
echo 'form action="https://www.sandbox..../cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="FDN9DZRLVBQRL">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox....scribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox....i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"> 
</form>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a hosted button, so you need to make sure that it was created from (and still exists in) the account you're testing with.

If you're testing with the sandbox you need to create the button from that sandbox account in order for it to work.

Keep in mind that is only the case when working with hosted buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the form action with this:

`<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">`

You are pointing to Sandbox endpoint, where the hosted button belongs to LIVE account.